# Is it okay that I upgraded my laptop to Windows 8.1 without drivers for Windows 8.1?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1

I bought a laptop last year, it had Window 7 Home Basic installed on it, and I've decided to upgrade it to Windows 8.1. I did a clean install, but when I search for drivers that are compatible with Windows 8.1, there are none. All I see is for Win XP or Win 7. So I tried to install driver pack solution, and yes, some driver are installed, but I think it's not like when it was on Windows 7.

I think there are some drivers that are not installed.

So here is my question: do I have to install Windows 7 again to bring back all drivers or can I just leave it? Is it okay for my laptop?

The model of the laptop was Toshiba Satellite L300-256, Pentium Dual-Core 2GHz, 3GB RAM.

Comment: What devices are you worried about exactly?  If its a display device, and you can't find 8.1 drivers, you shouldn't upgrade because the display model changed from `Windows 7` to `Windows 8` and again in `Windows 8.1` and will change yet again in `Windows 10`.

Comment: You need to make sure your processor is supported before you upgrade.  `Windows 8.1` added a few hardware features that were optional with `Windows 8` that are now required.

Comment: Yes, I am worried to my display driver and to my touchpad.
I've read the system requirements of 8.1 and my laptop compatible to its minimum requirements.

Comment: when I installed the driver pack solution, it installed a display driver and it works but I cant find the display menu or control panel.